# Django rest framework unit test viewsets mixins

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, django-rest-framework

I need to unit test a Django REST framework mixin. so i go for a test that looks like this:

```
class TestMyMixin(APITestCase):

    class DummyView(MyMixin,
        viewsets.ModelViewSet):
        queryset = MyModel.objects.all()
        serializer_class = MyModelSerializer

        #some properties omitted

    def setUp(self):
        self.view = self.DummyView.as_view(\
            actions={'get':'list'})

    def test_basic_query(self):
        instance = MyModel.objects.create(\
            **{'name':'alex'})
        request = APIRequestFactory().get(\
            '/fake-path?query=ale',
            content_type='application/json')
        response = self.view(request)
        self.assertEqual(\
            response.status_code,status.HTTP_200_OK)
        json_dict = json.loads(\
            response.content.decode('utf-8'))
        self.assertEqual(json_dict['name'],instance.name)
```

However when i run this test i do get the:

```
raise ContentNotRenderedError('The response content must be 'django.template.response.ContentNotRenderedError: The response content must be rendered before it can be accessed.
```

It seems that django REST framework would have some different approach to unit test `viewsets`, `mixins` and `views`.
But I can not figure out what should I do instead. 
The official docs page suggests to use real urls, but it suits more for acceptance tests rather than for unit tests.

Comment: Hey @canufeel I was wondering, did you find my answer helpful?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This problem occurs because your view's response doesn't get rendered, thus the `_is_rendered` is `False` and the `ContentNotRenderedError` exception gets raised.

You can see why and how this is happening, in the [django.template.response](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/template/response.py#L118) source code.

You can work around that problem by calling `.render()` manually on your response:

```
response = self.view(request)
self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_200_OK)

# Render the response manually
response.render()
json_dict = json.loads(response.content.decode('utf-8'))
self.assertEqual(json_dict['name'],instance.name)
```